# Exceptions not being caught using rosbridge version 1.0

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been developing an HTML5/Javascript GUI using version 1.0 of [rosbridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge) and most functions are working perfectly.  However, I just noticed that my Javascript is not catching rosbridge exceptions where I assume they should occur.  For example, if I follow [the tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge/Tutorials/Using%20Javascript%20to%20control%20ROS%20via%20rosjs) and run:

```
var connection = null;
try {
    connection = new ros.Connection("ws://foobar:1234");
} catch (err) {
    log('Failed to connect to rosbridge!');
    return;
}
log('Connection successful!');
```

where neither host foobar nor the port 1234 is valid, I don't see the "Failed to connect" message.  Instead I see the "Connection successful" message.  Similar exceptions such as trying to connect to a non-existent service are not being caught.  Is this a Javascript problem or a rosbridge problem?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45182/exceptions-not-being-caught-using-rosbridge-version-1.0/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-10-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is not the answer you are expecting, but I recently migrated from rosbridge 1.0 to rosbridge 2.0 and I'm extremely pleased with the results.

Rosbridge 2.0 is much more robust, consumes way less resources and has many other features.

If you already have a working websocket implementation, the migration shouldn't be hard at all.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) with karma: 651 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-10-05**:
Thanks @Victor.  Migrating to version 2.0 is probably the best answer so I'll give it a try.  I'll wait to see if anyone has a fix for version 1.0 before checking off your answer.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-10-11**:
@Victor: I'm finding the rosbridge 2.0 documentation very sparse and not sufficient for me to figure out how to translate my rosbridge 1.0 code to 2.0.  Do you know of any 2.0 examples out there that use the Javascript client in an HTML application?

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2012-10-14**:
No, I am sorry. I implemented a client using Qt in C++. But I believe all you need is a websocket client and on top of that implement the protocol described in this document: http://kforge.ros.org/rosbridge/trac/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/rosbridge%20protocol%20specification.pdf

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-10-23**:
@Pi Robot Did you eventually migrate to Rosbridge 2.0? Can you show the process of your migration?